# Is it possible to define constants in an email template?

Tags: email, email-template

I am using an email template with a massive number of URLs.
It has go to the stage where I'd like to define the URLs on the top of the page once and the use them in the template (some of them are used more than once).

Is this possible?

I'm guessing the closest, I could get would be to define them in a back end controller and then pull them in?

Comments welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using Visualforce email templates, you can do it inline without a controller:

`<apex:variable var="protocolAndHost" value="http://www.example.com" />`

```
<a href="{!protocolAndHost}/">home</a>
<a href="{!protocolAndHost}/about">about</a>
<a href="{!protocolAndHost}/contact">contact</a>
```

As food for thought, I'd also have pointed you at Custom Settings so you could keep the Email Template as text/html, [but it's a no go](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=0873000000086miAAA)!